# Possível bug input number no firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

Estava desenvolvendo um cálculo onde eu utilizei um campo number e um campo text, onde no campo number o usuário informaria a quantidade de um item e o campo text daria o valor do item cálculado. Em alguns testes realizados, quando o campo number é modificado através das setas do campo, ao resetar o formulário, o valor do campo number não é descartado. Tal erro acontece somente no firefox e apenas ao selecionar o valor um(1). Caso vc digite o número via teclado e reseta o formulário o erro não acontece. Nesse [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hywy395j/5/) do JSFIDDLE é possível verificar o erro. Existe alguma forma de corrigir isto?

Comment: Eu selecionei o valor `1` e o formulário foi resetado corretamente. Estou utilizando o Firefox 32 pelo Fedora 20.

Comment: Olá @Oeslei, repita esse procedimento duas vezes. O campo text não mostra o calculo.

Comment: Para reproduzir o problema: seta pra cima, verificar, seta pra cima.

Comment: O problema ocorre mesmo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente, ao chamar o método `reset` do formulário o valor do campo numérico não é considerado "mudado", de modo que quando você o passa novamente para `1` através das setas, ele não dispara o evento `onchange`.

Não sei por que isso ocorre, mas um *workaround* seria atribuir esse valor para zero antes de chamar o reset:

```
$(".ve").on("click", function(){ 
   alert('res');
   $("#quantidade").val(0); // O valor não será mais `1`
   $(this).parent().find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

[Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/hywy395j/6/). P.S. Se você resetar o formulário e usar a seta *pra baixo*, o segundo campo mostrará `NaN`. Seria interessante testar por `isNaN` no `change` para evitar isso.

Comment: Olá @mgibsonbr, A solução funcionou perfeitamente, e para prevenir o aparecimento do `NaN` adicionei a verificação: `if( $("#quantidade").val() >= '1' )`. Obrigado pela ajuda mais uma vez.